# Menubar in digiKam

Tags: 13.04, digikam

I do not see menu bar after fresh install of digiKam (3.1.0).

It was never displayed.

I found that maybe edit of `~/.kde/share/config/digikamrc` would help, but there is no `MenuBar=Disabled` anywhere.

Without menu the application is practically useless.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to add `MenuBar=Enabled` to the file? It helped in my case.

Comment: Are you using Unity?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> which switches the menu bar on and off.

Comment: In my case (digikam on windows) this was *exactly* the way to solve it. I can't understand why this was downvoted without comment.

Comment: This answer did not work for me.  Shaun of the Deads answer did. (I did not downvote)

Answer (score 3):

I've had to edit in 'MenuBar=Enabled' into that file you mentioned ( ~/.kde/share/config/digikamrc ).

When I next launched Digikam, the menu was there. However, after closing off that session and reopening Digikam at a later date, it was gone again.

Luckily with Ubuntu there's the HUD, so by hitting the left alt key and typing whatever I'm looking for I can so far get access to the features I need. And if I type 'settings', one for 'Show Menubar' re-appears. It's a really puzzling bug for sure.

Comment: This worked for me.  ianp5as answer did not work for me.