# digikam: organize imported images by date

Tags: photo-management, digikam

I am using digikam to import and organize pictures on my hard disks.

It seems that digikam is not reading the metadata to catalogue the pictures by date.

How can I force digikam to read the metadata and order images by date?

Answer (score 3):

So I'm guessing you're like me and you'd like to mimic Lightroom's way of listing the images?

After enabling the menubar ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421235/menubar-in-digikam/860558#860558)), go to:

**View > Group Images > Flat List**

Then do:

**View > Sort Images > By Date**

That ought to do it for you.

Lastly, if you're like me and have items in subfolders and wish to see them all at once (and not just images in the current folder you're in), go to:

**View > Include Album Sub-Tree**

Comment: I don't remember what Lightroom does, but sorting by Creation Date is great when merging photos from a proper camera and a smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not see the pictures arranged by date in the folder of the album, I see them organized by date when I click the dates tab on the side.

I will leave the post here for others to see. What confused me was the non-camera files (png, pdf, etc.) were shown by date in the album but not the camera images (.jpg).